# How to make a view scrollable with only one element like in the settings app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview

I want my app to have a view that can scroll even when there isn't always content to scroll to. For instance, the Wifi tab in settings is always scrollable. Is this a UIScrollView?
I'm using Storyboard, not SwiftUI by the way.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

I've tried using a UIScrollView but I think what I'm trying to achieve is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Settings app is using `UITableView` in "group" mode for most screens. The little bit of scrolling you can do even when there is little content is referred to as "bounce".

`UIScrollView` can also be used (`UITableView` extends `UIScrollView`). The bounce actually comes from the scroll view. You can enable the `bounces` property.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `UIScrollView`'s [`alwaysBounceVertical`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619383-alwaysbouncevertical) property:

> If the value of this property is `true` and [bounces](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619420-bounces) is `true`, the scroll view allows vertical dragging even if the content is smaller than the bounds of the scroll view. The default value is `false`.